# Fetch value from a collection without knowing keywords [Javascript through Discord API]

Tags: javascript, collections, discord

I'm working with Discord API and node.js. In a Discord server we can assign members to specific "roles". "Members" are one of them, "admin" is another. In this case we are working with a custom one, not that it matters.
When I'm fetching every member of a certain role on the Discord server the API returns a collection looking something like this:

```
RoleMembers = {userID:{user}, userID:{user}, userID:{user}, userID:{user}}
```

The problem is that without knowing the keywords (userID) I cannot fetch any data in the {user} object. I've tried treating it like an array and loop through an index, but it just returns undefined.

I have no clue on how to treat this data that the API is feeding me.

The API documentation tells me this is what is returned:

```
.members READ-ONLY

The cached guild members that have this role

Type: Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>
```

Tried with this loop, but it isn't giving me anything.:

```
var roles = message.channel.guild.roles;
var roleMembers = roles.get(settings.ptID).members;

for (var member in roleMembers) {
 var jsonMember = {
  ID:member.id,
  Name:member.nickname
 }
 obj.Members.push(member);
}
```

Is there any way for me to either transform the collection into an indexed array? Or to fetch the keywords so that I can make a loop to fetch the data I need in the user object? I'm honestly not even sure what a "collection" mean in this context, or how to make operations on it.

User /u/samuraijs over at /r/javascript gave me the following code:

```
Object.keys(roleMembers).map(userId => roleMembers[userId])
```

But running

```
Object.keys(roleMembers).map(userId => console.log(userId))
```

Gives me no console log. Still not sure what I'm doing wrong.